# How to change background Opacity when bootstrap modal is open

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal. When modal is open background content opacity is not changed by default. I tried changing in js using

```
function showModal() {
document.getElementById("pageContent").style.opacity = "0.5";
```

}

This is working but whenever modal is closed opacity style still remains for the pageContent. But, I am sure this is not the right way to do. Any help appreciated. Thanks.
Html button which opens Modal is

```
<button class="btn glossy-clear" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-display" onclick="showModal()">Clear</button>
```

Modal Code is

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal-display">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Search results</h4>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> 
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">Hello</div>
          <div class="col-md-5">i!!!!</div>
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

[image: modal-backdrop div]

Comment: Thanks for the answers.I tried all but still not working. I figured out in developer tools modal-backdrop div added  outside the form tag when modal is open, I am not sure if this is the cause. Added image to the question.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I am assuming you want to set the opacity of the modal background...

Set the opacity via CSS

```
.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:0.5 !important;
}
```

`!important` prevents the opacity from being overwritten - particularly from Bootstrap in this context.

Comment: If I do that even modal is transparent when open. But you reminded me of adding modal-backdrop class to the modal div. After this now background is black instead of transparent.

Comment: Dont add modal-backdrop to the modal div. The modal-background is the class that bootstrap uses for background on which modal appears. You just need to add this CSS to the page, that's it

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3 and adding !important messes up the opacity transition. This answer works great if you just take the important off. Here is what I did: 
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
 opacity: .5 or whatever you want;
}

Comment: Thanks for the solution. We're using this for a landing page where we're "gating" the content. I removed the "Close" x button and am trying to figure out how to make the modal-background non-clickable. Visitors are required to complete the form before viewing content. Let me know if anyone knows a good way to do this.

Comment: UPDATE to the above comment: I applied the following to the modal div to prevent clicking outside-the-modal clicking and closing.:

data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"

Answer (score 28):

You can override the modal-backdrop opacity in your stylesheet [take note of the .in class]

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThisIsMarkSantiago/r0gwn005/1/

Comment: Better answer, this solution keeps the fade transition

Answer (score 15):

you could utilize bootstrap [events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):: as

```
//when modal opens
$('#yourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#pageContent").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
})

//when modal closes
$('#yourModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#pageContent").css({ opacity: 1 });
})
```

Comment: This method worked good for me aswell, I used a different select for the backdrop though, not sure about the #pageContent bit. This code was used to remove the Darkening Effect.
`
  $("#busy-modal").on('shown.bs.modal',function(e){
   $('div.modal-backdrop').css('opacity',0);
  });
  $("#busy-modal").on('hidden.bs.modal',function(e){
   $('div.modal-backdrop').css('opacity',0.5);
  });
`

Answer (score 12):

Just in case someone is using Bootstrap 4. It seems we can no longer use `.modal-backdrop.in`, but must now use `.modal-backdrop.show`. Fade effect preserved.

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with overriding using `!important` is that you will loose the **fade in effect**.

So the actual best trick to change the modal-backdrop opacity **without breaking the fadeIn effect** and **without having to use the shameless** `!important` is to use this :

```
.modal-backdrop{
  opacity:0; transition:opacity .2s;
}
.modal-backdrop.in{
  opacity:.7;
}
```

**@sass**

```
.modal-backdrop{
  opacity:0; transition:opacity .2s;
  &.in{opacity:.7;}
}
```

Simple and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Just setting height to 100% won't be the solution if you have a background page whose height extends beyond browser height.

Adding to Bhargavi's answer, this is the solution when you have scrollable page in the background.

```
.modal-backdrop.in
{
    opacity:0.5 !important;
    position:fixed;// This makes it cover the entire scrollable page, not just browser height
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```js
$("#your_modal_id").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
      $('.modal-backdrop.in').css('opacity', '0.9');
});
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.  This enables a stronger fade a only one of the modal instances instead of affecting the others, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using REACT Bootstrap 5 and typescript. Tried many of the above and none work.

Finally got it work with

```
.fade.modal-backdrop.show{
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

if you want to change it for one specific modal, add a new backdropClassName style to the component

in jsx:

```
<Modal show={this.show} backdropClassName="newBackdrop" ...>
```

in css:

```
.fade.modal-backdrop.newBackdrop.show{
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a day of struggling I figured out setting height :100% to .modal-backdrop.in class worked. height : 100% made opacity to show up whole page.

Comment: But what if you have the page as scrollable? This would not cover the whole page then

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the less version to compile Bootstrap modify @modal-backdrop-opacity in your variables override file $modal-backdrop-opacity for scss.

Answer (score 1):

Adding !important to .modal-backdrop will ruin the transition on bootstrap modal

I achieved changing modal overlay background by direct edit in **bootstrap.min.css**. Those who are using bootstrap CSS locally (without using CDN) can change the background-color value of **.modal-backdrop** class.

If you want to change bootstrap 4 modal overlay opacity find this class **.modal-backdrop.show** and change opacity to the value you need.

If want to change overlay transition timing add transition to **.modal-backdrop.fade** class

If want to change transition timing for modal object change transition values in **.modal.fade .modal-dialog** class

Comment: provide an example to increase understanding and get more likes

Answer (score 1):

You can download a custom compiled bootstrap 3, just customize the @modal-backdrop-opacity from:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

Customizing bootstrap 4 requires compiling from source, overriding $modal-backdrop-bg as described in:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/

In the answers to
[Bootstrap 4 custom build generator / download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725946/bootstrap-4-custom-build-generator-download) there is a NodeJS workflow for compiling Bootstrap 4 from source, alone with some non-official Bootstrap 4 customizers.

Answer (score 1):

```
.modal-backdrop {
opacity: 0.7!important;
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: You can get rid of the `!important` if you make the rule more specific:
`.modal-backdrop.show` or `div.modal-backdrop.show` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, I clear the opacity in .modal.backdrop.in

```
.modal-backdrop.in{
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:.5
    }
```

change it to

```
.modal-backdrop.in{
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the opacity by the last parameter of `rgb` function.

the opacity is `0.5` in the example

```css
.modal-backdrop {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with:

```
.modal:before{
   opacity:0.001 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on bootstrap 5

```
    <Modal
      ...
      backdropClassName="opacity-100" // it can be 0, 25, 75, 100
    >
```

Comment: Please explain how your code solved OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

Update for **Bootstrap 5.3**, You just need to adjust the body tag and add it to css selector to reach the .modal-backdop class. just like this.

```
body.modal-open .modal-backdrop {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```