# How to add background-image title using CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
header {
   float: left;
   padding: 5px 0 0 0 ;
   width: 100%;
   background-image:url('../img/Kef_Beach.jpg');
```

}

I need to add background-image title also. How can i add using css only.

Comment: Some codes would be gr8 to illustrate the issue......

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096346/how-to-change-background-opacity-when-bootstrap-modal-is-open

Comment: But Its affecting to all modal in that html page. And the modal become diactive. I am not able click on close and ok button.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id or unique class to that modal container and apply css rules. If that does not have work..You may need to go to the extreme of adding `!important;` to new attributes changed.

Also note that you are not overriding all css rule if you just insert `.fade.in{}`. You need to insert what attributes you'd like to override, for example is it `opacity`, `background-color`?

Take for example this

```css
body{
background:green;
}
.modal-box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  color:blue;
  opacity:1;
}
#override{
  background:blue;
  color:red;
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-box" id='override'>
Modal Box
</div>
```

**What have you noticed in this snippet?**

I override background color, font color and opacity of the div by adding those new rules after the modal-box rules.

Comment: But In my case id auto generating i cant use id.

Comment: <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>

Comment: .fade.in {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

Comment: When i deactivate this fade.in then modal coming properly.

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle with all your codes inside?.I can look at it.....empty fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/