# How to get bootstrap 4 24 grid

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know where to download 24 grid version of newest bootstrap 4-0-0 beta?
I don't want to use sass, and I cant find customize option in bootstrap website.

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/W4pRJD4tJI/bootstrap-4-_-24-columns,-16-columns,-or-32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 24-columns grid using the [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns), or by combining the 12-column grid..

https://www.codeply.com/go/nnf7toD1E2

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            ..
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            24
        </div>
 </div>
```

Or, you can generate a [custom CSS build](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/bootstrap-4-customizer) by changing the $grid-columns variable to 24.

Comment: Amazing... the auto-layout feature is really powerful. Thanks for sharing this succinct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no customization tool in Bootstrap 4 so custom build is a necessary step.

But don't worry, it's quite easy.

1. Follow instructions from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251052/1614120 (you'll need Node.js installed)
2. Put following code in the `name.scss` (file mentioned in 5th step):

*name.scss*

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$grid-columns: 24; // This overrides default value (12)
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

3. Compile (step 7).

If you need any other Bootstrap components apart from the grid, see step 5 of the instructions.