# Define different number of Bootstrap 4 columns for some part (div) of page only?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

By default Bootstrap 4 has 12 columns. It is possible to change the number of columns by (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) creating custom.scss file and SASS-compiling it into css file that will replace the default Bootstrap css file. It can be done by overriding variables:

```
$grid-gutter-width: 14px;
$grid-columns: 24;
```

This works for the entire page. But I have some region of the page with completely different structure. Is it possible to define distinct number of Bootstrap columns for some region only?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to create 24 columns across each row is to use the [auto-layout grid explained in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264696/171456).

However, if you need a *complete* 24-column grid with all of the responsive breakpoints...

**Option 1**

One option is to create a custom SASS @mixin (very similar to the Bootstrap 4 make-grid-columns mixin). Notice in the mixin that I used `.col24-` instead of `.col-`...

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

@mixin make-custom-grid-columns($columns: $grid-columns, $gutter: $grid-gutter-width, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  %grid-column {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px; // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
    padding-right: ($gutter / 2);
    padding-left: ($gutter / 2);
  }

  @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $breakpoints);

    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
      .col24#{$infix}-#{$i} {
        @extend %grid-column;
      }
    }
    
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      .col24#{$infix} {
        flex-basis: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      .col24#{$infix}-auto {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: none;
      }

      @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        .col24#{$infix}-#{$i} {
          @include make-col($i, $columns);
        }
      }

      @for $i from 0 through $columns {
        .order#{$infix}-#{$i} { order: $i; }
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}


@include make-custom-grid-columns(24, 10px, $grid-breakpoints);


/* remember to import Bootstrap after the changes */ 
@import "bootstrap";
```

This allows the standard 12 unit grid (`.col-*`) to co-exist with the 24 unit grid (`col24-*`) so you can use either as needed.

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/GFkzKlFyX2

**Option 2**

Another option is to extend a custom container (ie:`container-24`) class for the the 24 column grid. This would allow you to simply use `container-24` for the custom grid, and the row, col-* would remain the conventional (`col-{breakpoint}-1` .. `col-{breakpoint}-24`)...

```
.container-24 {
    @include make-container();
    @include make-container-max-widths($container-24-max-widths, $grid-breakpoints);

    /*  custom cols- 24 column grid with 6px gutter */
    @include make-grid-columns(24, 6px, $grid-breakpoints);
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/Adfnwh9p4x

---

IMO, the [auto-layout grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264696/171456) is the simpler option as this custom build will add a lot of extra "weight" to the CSS.

---

Related: [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap 4 with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142)

Answer (score 0):

You can create 24-columns grid using the auto-layout columns Or, you can generate a custom [CSS builder](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/bootstrap-4-customizer) by changing the $grid-columns variable to 24.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      .....
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        24
    </div>
```