# Custom main content to column proportion using bootstrap v4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap v4 I am trying to create a basic blog article layout with main content and a right-hand column.

When using a col-9 and col-3 layout the righthand column is too wide, and conversely col-10 and col-2 results in the main content column being too wide and over bearing.

In terms of proportions a col-9 col-2 works, but that is only 11 not 12 columns and the content appears to be left-of center since 1/12th on he right hand size is empty.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <h1 class="mt-2">My Title</h1>
            <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col right-column">
            <?= $this->element('right-column-home'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this goal of main content to column proportion which is more than 9/3 and less than 10/2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557311/6127393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add `.justify-content-center` to the parent `.row` and the child `.col-*`s will be centered horizontally. The [examples in the docs for this class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content) all use `.d-flex` and not `.row` but keep in mind a `.row` is already a flexbox container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row justify-content-center my-2">
    <div class="col-9 bg-primary">
      <p>.container > .row.justify-content-center > .col-9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 bg-secondary">
      <p>.col-2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

However you do end up with a more narrow row then another using 12 columns:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row justify-content-center my-2">
    <div class="col-9 bg-primary">
      <p>.col-9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 bg-secondary">
      <p>.col-2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center my-2">
    <div class="col-6 bg-primary">
      <p>.col-6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-secondary">
      <p>.col-6</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

To keep the ratio of widths and still fill the width of the container, just define your own custom column classes with defined widths. In the example below I define the styles in the same way bootstrap does for each `.col-#` :

```css
.col-main {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 81.818182%;
  flex: 0 0 81.818182%;
  max-width: 81.818182%;
}

.col-right {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 18.181818%;
  flex: 0 0 18.181818%;
  max-width: 18.181818%;
}
```

```css
.col-main {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 81.818182%;
  flex: 0 0 81.818182%;
  max-width: 81.818182%;
}

.col-right {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 18.181818%;
  flex: 0 0 18.181818%;
  max-width: 18.181818%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-main bg-primary text-light">
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <p>
        Content.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right bg-dark text-light">
      <h3>Right</h3>
      <ul class="list-group bg-dark">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">A</li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">B</li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 bg-secondary text-light text-right">
      Twelve columns here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/4b210n3p/2/