# What happened to bootstrap customize?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 3 used to have this customize option: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

However, I'm unable to find such a link for Bootstrap 4. I'm just building a simple website and won't be using 80% of it's functionality for sure. I don't want most of the JS functionalities too. How do I go about this?

Comment: Here is a [BS4 customizer](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/bootstrap-4-customizer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not yet in Bootstrap 4 afaik.

But you can modify the SCSS file and build the Bootstrap css and js file.

This is what @mdo say about it

> This is essentially the same as commenting out an import statement in bootstrap.scss. I know there's a bit more to it when it comes to shared components, but it's basically 1:1. It's been requested before and I was a pass then, still am now.

Check the Bootstrap issue/feature-request [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24653)

Example

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/print";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
//@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions";
```

**Update:**

This is a very good online Bootstrap customizer [Bootstrap.build](https://bootstrap.build)

Comment: I ended up using Bootstrap 3 customized to just 51kb total of both css and js. Bootstrap 4 is just too big for this particular project! Thanks.

Comment: That looks very good indeed, is there a way to change the features? Otherwise I'll still have to comment out the lines and compile from there myself.

Comment: I doubt if we can change a particular feature as some are linked to other features. But you can try commenting out in sass file and see if get complied else revert the changes

Answer (score 2):

There will **not** be a customizer at all for Bootstrap 4:

> Dropped the online Customizer in favor of more extensive setup
>   documentation and customized builds.

(*[source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#global-changes)*)

However if you want to customize Bootstrap in the web, you can use a third party tool like http://bootstrapcustomizer.com/.

Comment: Why officially dropped the online customize tool, even though its useful?

Comment: @iamjustcoder I haven't found any more extensive statement than the info I cited...