# Building Bootstrap 4 with Sass - result not same as dist/bootstrap.css

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Sass and trying to compile Bootstrap so I can change the md breakpoint such that a menu will display in touch mode on a 7inch tablet.

Before I made any changes, I thought I'd make sure I can compile it OK by doing a diff on my complied version vs the one on the dist directory - however the file I've complied is over 20kb smaller than the one in dist (V4 downloaded today).

I open the files hoping it would be just whitespace and comments, but there are actual differences in the CSS.

My build process is below.

```
$ sass -v
Sass 3.5.5 (Bleeding Edge)


$ pwd
/Volumes/projects/xx/resp/bootstrap-4.0.0

$ dir
drwxrwxr-x   4 xx  staff   16384 12 Feb  2018 dist
...
drwxrwxr-x   4 xx  staff   16384 12 Feb  2018 scss




$ sass -f scss/bootstrap.scss dist/css/TESTbootstrap.css

$ dir dist/css

-rwxrw-r--  1 kevin  xx  152719 12 Feb  2018 TESTbootstrap.css
...
-rwxrw-r--  1 kevin  x  178152 18 Jan 10:29 bootstrap.css
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses autoprefixer to apply vendor prefixes (such as `-webkit`) to the compiled CSS. You should set up a NodeJS project to compile. Check the `package.json` file in the Bootstrap repo to understand what happens during the build process of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there a guide on how to do that? Is there any other way to change the breakpoint. In Bootstrap V3 you could configure a custom build - is this not available with V4?

Comment: I think I have node working

Comment: If you want to customize online, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48415119/8918893

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out those links