# Bootstrap customization comes up with unexpected view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I tried to customize bootstrap in two different ways:

1-  via https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ 
2- through bower component, here is my folder structure 
[my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVHKC.png) 
But both time facing the same problem. like this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJOAG.png)
Please anyone can help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first approach, you have customised `bootstrap-3`. It does not work for bootstrap-4. As far as I know, you can not customise `bootstrap-4` that way. But you can do `SASS` files of it. For more info, visit this link

#### [bootstrap.com - customise options](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the Bootstrap 3 customizer for Bootstrap 4. Bootstrap doesn't offer an *official* customization tool for Bootstrap 4 as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725946/bootstrap-4-custom-build-generator-download).

You can [customize with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-4-with-sass/49070142#49070142), or use a tool that will build the CSS for you such as:
[Bootstrap 4 customizer](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/bootstrap-4-customizer) or [Themestr.app](https://themestr.app) (These are my tools)

If you're only looking to customize the **Navbar color**, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530995/171456).