# Use Config.json to customize Bootstrap 4

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to use config.json (created in [bootstrap 3 customize page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/)) to create bootstrap 4 custom.scss as said in [Theming Bootstrap page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)?

The question [Bootstrap 4 custom build generator / download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45725946/3424212) is about a customization page, not about using config.json to create a custom.scss.

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible. Bootstrap 3 config file was a file created for the online compiler, so you could save the options and recreate the previous compilation in their website customizer anytime. Bs3 and 4 have a lot of options. One and the most important is that bs3 is primarily created in Less and Bs4 is just Sass. I don’t think this could be done without studying the config file and find a way to transpile the configuration to a sass file to configure bs4.

Comment: There are 3rd party [tools like this](http://whootstrap.themes.guide/) for customizing Bootstrap 4, or you can re-compile yourself with SASS.