# How to use Bootstrap 3 or 4 - 16 & 24 grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have designed a Bootstrap 24 psd grid website template but, now I am confused how to use this 24 or 16 psd grids in Bootstrap 3 or 4 because Bootstrap only provides 12 col grid system. 
Anyone there with a proper solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no customization tool in Bootstrap 4 so custom build is a necessary step.

But don't worry, it's quite easy.

1. Follow instructions from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251052/1614120 (you'll need Node.js installed)
2. Put following code in the `name.scss` (file mentioned in 5th step):

*name.scss*

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Set this value to 16, 24, etc. depending on how many columns you need.
$grid-columns: 24;

@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

3. Compile (step 7).

If you need any other Bootstrap components apart from the grid, see step 5 of the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**You can customize bootstrap and change the grid from 12 according to your 16 or 24 grids.**

just go to the following link and customize bootstrap and then download bootstrap.

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as above – styling sass/less as you expected or you can just nest columns inside of columns like so:    [click.](http://jsfiddle.net/robertgrzonka/wymdp3tb/)

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    1/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    2/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    3/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    4/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    5/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    6/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    7/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    8/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    9/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    10/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    11/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    12/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    13/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    14/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    15/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    16/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    17/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    18/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    19/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    20/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    21/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    22/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    23/24
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    24/24
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```