# twitter-bootstrap ( removing unused code from bootstrap.css)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is anyone aware if it is possible to remove large sections of the bootstrap 3 css code that I am not using on my websites to make the file smaller and load faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 custom build generator / download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725946/bootstrap-4-custom-build-generator-download)

Comment: for what is worth, bootstrap 3 has a similar customizer section

Comment: Oh, I misread your question and thought you're asking about Bootstrap 4. As ochi said, [there is a tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. But if you want to load your site faster you should use CDN links instead of putting files in you own server.

Comment: You actually **can** customize bootstrap and include only required components. You need to build it yourself, or use some third party tool.

Comment: Thanks ... I was finding ref to software tools like that in google but haven't located one to use yet.