# Is it a bug? Issues using BoostrapVue Modal 'backdrop' and closing buttons

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

BoostrapVue **Modal** 'backdrop' and interaction issues

I'm currently doing a project in Vue3 using BoostrapVue. I'm new using these technologies and when trying to use the modal the simplest way ([using the the examples in the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#component-reference)) I have problems interacting with the closing buttons (not working at all) of the modal in addition to having to use 'hide-backdrop' property to avoid one extra backdrop which only spoils the aforementioned interaction and display of the Modal...

[Interaction not working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blj74.png)

Is this a bug or it's solvable?

I've trying to fix my issue and... The only possible solution it's to create a personalized modal? I really would like to use the already created component with all its properties.

[Similar problem here I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082097/bootstrap-vue-modal-black-background)